# Calling a Method - Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, methods, watir-webdriver

I am new to automation and I have started using Watir Webdriver to automate a website. However, there are certain pieces of code which can be reused for multiple test cases. How can I group the reusable pieces of code into a method which I can call in every test case ? Could you please provide references or examples ?

Comment: You should really read a book on Ruby. Watir is just a Ruby software. Methods are a Ruby feature, not a Watir feature.

Comment: The approach might depend on which test framework you are using. However, you probably want to look into the concept of creating page objects.

Comment: Page Objects discussion here: https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/wiki/Page-Objects

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in methods.

Here is an example:

```
def automation_snippet
  @browser.text_field(:id => 'field_id').set 'foo'
end
```

Later you will probably be interested in classes, page objects, and modules.

This is basic ruby stuff. You will need to make sure that whatever method you want to use is in scope, too.

So, keywords to start with are methods and scope. If you are using Cucumber, then you can define methods in any step definition file and they will be available in all your other Cucumber tests.